# Creating code representing the Position Analysis of a Slider Crank Mechanism using a Newton Raphson Method.

Tags: jquery, matlab, computer-science

I am trying to create a Position Analysis code of a Slider Crank Mechanism in MATLAB.

I keep getting the following error in code and I cant understand how to fix it. Could someone give me some guidance.

> > Undefined function 'solve' for input arguments of type 'char'.
>
> Error in SliderCrank (line 20) solC = solve(eqnC, 'xCsol' );

The code is below

```
    % Position analysis
% R-RRT
clear % clears all variables from the workspace
clc % clears the command window and homes the cursor
close all % closes all the open figure windows
% Input data
AB=0.5;
BC=1;
phi = pi/4;
% Position of joint A (origin)
xA = 0; yA = 0;
% Position of joint B - position of the driver link
xB = AB*cos(phi);
yB = AB*sin(phi);
% Position of joint C
yC = 0;
% Distance formula: BC=constant
eqnC = '( xB - xCsol )ˆ2 + ( yB - yC )ˆ2 = BCˆ2';
% Solve the above equation
solC = solve(eqnC, 'xCsol' );
% solve symbolic solution of algebraic equations
% Two solutions for xC - vector form

% first component of the vector solC
xC1=eval(solC(1));
% second component of the vector solC
xC2=eval(solC(2));
% eval executes string as an expression or statement
% Select the correct position for C
% for the given input angle
if xC1 > xB
   xC = xC1; 
else xC = xC2; 
end
% if conditionally executes statements
% Angle of the link 2 with the horizontal
phi2 = atan((yB-yC)/(xB-xC));
fprintf('Results \n\n')
% Print the coordinates of B
fprintf('xB = %g (m)\n', xB)
fprintf('yB = %g (m)\n', yB)
% Print the coordinates of C
fprintf('xC = %g (m)\n', xC)
fprintf('yC = %g (m)\n', yC)
% Print the angle phi2
fprintf('phi2 = %g (degrees) \n', phi2*180/pi)

% Graphic of the mechanism
plot([xA,xB],[yA,yB],'r-o',... 
[xB,xC],[yB,yC],'b-o'),...
xlabel('x (m)'),...
ylabel('y (m)'),...
title('positions for \phi = 45 (deg)'),...
text(xA,yA,' A'),...
text(xB,yB,' B'),...
text(xC,yC,' C'),...
axis([-0.2 1.4 -0.2 1.4]),...
grid
% the commas and ellipses (...) after the commands
% were used to execute the commands together
% end of program
```

Comment: This function requires the Symbolic Math Toolbox maybe you don't have it?

Comment: You were right.  It just took me more diagnosis to find that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that appears on the `solve` [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/solve.html) is:

> `solve` does not accept string inputs containing multiple input
>   arguments. In future releases, string inputs will be deprecated. In
>   place of string inputs, first declare the variables using `syms` and
>   pass them as a comma-separated list or vector.

So you need to have:

```
syms xCsol
eqnC = ( xB - xCsol )ˆ2 + ( yB - yC )ˆ2 == BCˆ2; % no single quotes, so not a string, need ==
% Solve the above equation
solC = solve(eqnC, xCsol ); % no single quotes here either
```

Comment: Ok I see what your saying but "where" would i need to make this correction, thanks for helping am304.  Do I need to replace line 20 with it.

Comment: I've told you exactly where to make the correction, read my answer again. Replace the lines in your code (from `eqnC =` to `solC = `) with the ones in my answer.

Comment: Undefined function 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'.  This is the error I get now... does the syms xCsol stay above eqnC

Comment: Then you don't have the Symbolic Maths Toolbox, and you can't use the `solve` function (you can double-check by typing `ver` at the command line, although I would expect you to know which toolboxes you have). There's nothing I can do for you.

Comment: Which begs the question: is this really your code or did you "lift" it from somewhere else?

Comment: This is certainly my code. But to be honest Im not really very familiar with matlab. And no I didnt initally purchase matlab with that toolbox.  At least I know I need to buy it for these type of programs.  Thanks.